# How to remove pricing in Magento 1.9.2.2 using fall-back approach

Tags: xml, magento

I have a store running on Magento C.E. I have a template that I purchased and installed. Everything is running properly.
I need to customize some parts of the store and make some modifications to let's say the product detail page.
I am tempted to do that the quick way: Go to the phtml file and comment or remove what I want to remove.
But I am reading that the best practice calls for using the fall back approach.
I am familiar with some aspects of the hierarchy of the themes default > rwd > my purchased template.

But can someone give a detailed example of how to let's say remove the pricing from the product detail page using the fall back method?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make use of overrides and child themes.

Go to Settings->General-> Design->Themes and add:

```
Templates: {{Name of your child theme e.g custom}}
Skin (Images / CSS): {{Name of your child theme e.g custom}}
Layout: {{Name of your child theme e.g custom}}
Default: {{Name of the theme you are using}}
```

Create the following folders

In design create a folder named e.g"custom" inside {{package}} folder
and add the basic folder structure:

- "layout"
- "locale"
- "template"

Do the same for skin folder at `skin/frontend/{{package}}`

Create folder custom and add folders

- "css"
- "images"
- "js"

To use overrides just copy a file to the corresponding folder of your child theme.
e.g

```
frontend/{{package}}/{{theme}}/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
```

To your 
E.g copy

```
frontend/{{package}}/custom/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
```